# How to highlight characters after mouse hover?

Tags: html, css, animation, css-selectors, css-transitions

[image]

I am trying to create this effect in CSS. So far I just able to get this effect in the reverse order. This means when I hover the mouse in the first letter, it highlights all the other text/character(he story of we) after it. Is it possible to reverse the below effect that currently working, or is there any other solution to get this effect?

```css
 span:hover ~ span {
     color: black;
     background-color: yellow;
 }
```

```html
 <div>
      <span>T</span>
      <span>h</span>
      <span>e</span>
      <span> </span>
      <span>S</span>
      <span>t</span>
      <span>o</span>
      <span>r</span>
      <span>y</span>
      <span> </span>
      <span>o</span>
      <span>f</span>
      <span> </span>
      <span>w</span>
      <span>e</span>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get the desired result by reversing your reversed effect :)

I highlight all the characters on `div:hover` and unhighlight them on `div:hover span:hover ~ span` so it all works out in the end.

```css
div {
  background-color: black;
  display: inline-block;
}

div:hover span {
  color: black;
  background-color: yellow;
}

span {
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 32px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

div:hover span:hover ~ span {
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div>
<span>T</span><span>h</span><span>e</span><span> </span><span>S</span><span>t</span><span>o</span><span>r</span><span>y</span><span> </span><span>o</span><span>f</span><span> </span><span>W</span><span>e</span>
</div>
```